# React setState with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a simple problem here with creating dynamic keys for a state object in React using `computed property names`, but after trying for hours I can't figure out how to fix it.

See the comments in the code for details, and a short overview below.

**Scenario**: a user clicks on an option inside a given page and the `updateSelection` method below is called. This method updates the state with new information.

**Problem**: Using `computed property names` I think(?) makes the keys be unique inside of an object, and any future keys of the same name are replaced. In some cases, I want to allow multiple selections of the same page, this is the part that I can't figure out. I'm open to turning my state into an array of objects if that works better.

```
state = {
  userSelection: {}
}

const updateSelection = page => {
  const { pageName, category, multiple } = page;

  const selection = {
    pageName,
    category
  }

  // If `multiple` is false, pages must be unique in the state object.
  // This currently works fine.
  if (!multiple) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userSelection: {
        ...prevState.userSelection,
        [pageName]: selection
      }
    }));

    // New state for userSelection is now this:
    // { 
    //   Page 1: {pageName: "Page 1", category: X}, 
    //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: Y}
    // }

    return;
  }

  // If `multiple` is true for a page, the same page key can be added to
  // the state object as long as the category is different. If the category
  // is the same, the page is replaced just like when `multiple` is false.
  // The desired result for userSelection would look something like this:
  // { 
  //   Page 1: {pageName: "Page 1", category: X}, 
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: Y},
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: Z},
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: W, other unique props}
  // }
}
```

**Update**: for deleting a page, the input would be the `pageName` which could be passed as an argument to a `deletePage` method similar to `updateSelection`.

Comment: Javascript object keys must all be unique, so I am afraid, `{ 
  //   Page 1: {pageName: "Page 1", category: X}, 
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: Y},
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: Z},
  //   Page 2: {pageName: "Page 2", category: W, other unique props}
  // }` isn't really possible

Comment: What you could have instead is an array of objects

Comment: Would agree with @ShubhamKhatri. You can make an array of objects instead of having just one value for a page in your state. Managing those pages should be piece of the cake after that.

Comment: "piece of cake" - perhaps similar to baking, not eating :) Blueshift, if you need more features than in my answer, e.g. deleting pages, please add a new "update" section with examples of input/output and notify me (currently you ask to keep at most 1 page per category, but did not mention deletion, so no idea how to detect if some other action is needed sometimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use an **array** for multiple values of each page, like this:

```
{ 
  "Page 1": [ {pageName: "Page 1", category: X} ], 
  "Page 2": [
    {pageName: "Page 2", category: Y},
    {pageName: "Page 2", category: Z},
    {pageName: "Page 2", category: W, other unique props}
  ]
}
```

then you can adapt following code for adding/replacing items in the arrays:

```js
function updateSelection ({pageName, category, multiple}) {
  const selection = {pageName, category} // assuming more props here
  if (!multiple) {} // TODO keep old code or change to arrays too
  
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const {userSelection} = prevState
    if (!userSelection.hasOwnProperty(pageName)) {
      userSelection[pageName] = []
    }
    let categoryWasReplaced = false
    const nextUserSelection = {
      ...userSelection,
      [pageName]: userSelection[pageName].map(item => {
        // TODO use .filter() if needed to remove from selection
        if (item.category === category) {
          categoryWasReplaced = true
          return selection
        }
        return item
      })
    }
    if (!categoryWasReplaced) {
      nextUserSelection[pageName].push(selection)
    }
    return {userSelection: nextUserSelection}
  })
}

// ### test ###
let state = {userSelection: {}}
const mockSetState = f => {
  state = {...state, ...f(state)}
}
const testUpdateSelection = updateSelection.bind({state, setState: mockSetState})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 1', category: 'X', multiple: true})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 2', category: 'Y', multiple: true})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 2', category: 'Y', multiple: true})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 2', category: 'Y', multiple: true})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 2', category: 'Z', multiple: true})
testUpdateSelection({pageName: 'Page 2', category: 'W', multiple: true})
console.log(state)
```

Comment: Thank you for the completeness of your answer, Aprillion! I have gone ahead and adopted the same format for the state when `!multiple`, so: `[pageName]: [selection]`. I've also updated my post with input information for deleting a page (thank you for this too BTW, I was thinking of doing that as well).